# Selection from two Lists using Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring-el

I have two objects whose signature is as follows:

Employee{String name, int id, String address, Long salary}

Department{String name, List{Employee} employeesList}

Usign Spring Expression Language I have to find out the Department_name of a particular employee say 'A'.

My spel context has two lists #employees and #departments which are populated with required objects.

I couldn't find any way to need this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Raj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
"#departments.?[!employeesList.?[name=='A'].isEmpty()]"
```

If you are sure that your employee exists and is in only one department, you can get the department name with this:

```
"#departments.?[!employeesList.?[name=='A'].isEmpty()][0].name"
```